# NightmareJS .click() method - selector issue

Tags: javascript, events, dom, css-selectors, click

I cannot make nightmareJS to click the search button, although .type() works well. 
What could be the issue?

```
.type('form[action="/search/web/direct_search.php"] [class=_1frb]', string)
.click('form[action="/search/web/direct_search.php"] [type=submit]')
//.click('#js_x > form > button')
//.click('button[class="_42ft _4jy0 _4w98 _4jy3 _517h _51sy"]')
```

Developer Tools console finds the button:

```
 document.querySelector('form[action="/search/web/direct_search.php"] [type=submit]')
 <button value=​"1" class=​"_42ft _4jy0 _4w98 _4jy3 _517h _51sy" aria-label=​"Search" tabindex=​"-1" data-testid=​"facebar_search_button" type=​"submit">​…​</button>​
```

Later Edit:

There you go, my friend, I've removed the import and put everything in a single file, I'm already logged in with the cookie, so this is the full code that replicates the issue:

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({
    show: true
});
var string = "TEST";
var search = function(string) {
    return function(nightmare) {
        nightmare
            .goto('http://www.facebook.com')
            .wait('form[action="/search/web/direct_search.php"] [class=_1frb]')
            .type('form[action="/search/web/direct_search.php"] [class=_1frb]', string)
            .click('form[action="/search/web/direct_search.php"] [type=submit]')
            // .click('#js_x > form > button')
            // .click('button[class="_42ft _4jy0 _4w98 _4jy3 _517h _51sy"]')
            .wait(2000)
            .screenshot('after.png')
            .then(function() {
                return nightmare
                    .wait();
            })
    };
};
nightmare
    .useragent('...')
    .use(search(string))
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: @JoeC I've updated my post accordingly.

Comment: I'm going to assume by that edit that you haven't read my post on how to debug.

Comment: @JoeC I have read your post. You can see that I've shown that the console finds the button using the same selector. It's a debug action.

Answer (score 1):

Nightmare's `.type()` emits keyboard events. You can "press" the return key with unicode values like so: `.type('selector', '\u000d')`. The example I provided below should work fine.

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var nightmare = Nightmare({
    show: true
});

nightmare
    .goto("http://www.facebook.com")
    .wait('form[action="/search/web/direct_search.php"] [class=_1frb]')
    .type('form[action="/search/web/direct_search.php"] [class=_1frb]', "test\u000d")
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

Normally when searching on Facebook, the suggestions menu opens as you type a query. Pressing the search button should then search immediately search. However, if you watch Nightmare's execution, you will see the suggestions suggestions menu glitches out and closes when typing (this is electron browser's fault). So I believe you would have to press the search button twice; once to open the menu, then again to actually search.

Either way it is easier and nicer just to send a return key event.